# Adding pictures from PDF

Tags: overleaf, includegraphics

I am using Overleaf for PDF creation and I intend to upload pictures from `.PDF` but somehow the `includegraphics` is not working. I have used the `\usepackage{graphicx}` but still the error is

> dfTeX error: pdflatex (file /compile/4.pdf): PDF inclusion: required page does not exist <1>
>
> ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!

Could someone please help me? I have used the `includepdf` for the figure but it sort of adds a page with its setting and is not allowing me to trim.

Comment: Hello Staph! Tom from Overleaf Support Team here. I don't know what could cause this. But you can reach me on Overleaf support email address and we can see what's going on there. Then if it's something worth sharing with others, I will make an answer here.

Comment: Thank you. I will do so and mentioned this link in the support.